# Детектировать попытку закрытия окна

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Из главного окна открывается ещё окно, в котором выводится контент внутри iframe.  В контенте есть кнопка, вызывающая window.close(). Эта кнопка не работает. Можно ли без изменения кода в контенте закрывать окно, в котором выводится контент, с помощью этой кнопки? Например, повесить какой-то обработчик.

Comment: Важный момент, все в одном домене?

Comment: В разных доменах.

Comment: То есть правильно я понимаю, что вы просто вообще не хотите показывать свой сайт во фреймах? Это обычно решается не на клиенте, а установкой серверного заголовка.  
Обычно доступ из фрейма к родительскому окну window.top или window.parent. Но просто window.top.close() скорее всего не сработает из-за ограничений безопасности, да еще из фрейма загруженного с другого домена.

Comment: Если же вы хотите сам фрейм закрыть, а не родительское окно, а оно не закрывается, то для этого есть chrome-only хак: window.open(location, '_self').close();

Потому что вообще говоря, по крайним спекам закрывать из js можно только окна которые открыты из js (ограничения безопасности)

Comment: Т.е. по сути делать window.close можно только для окон которые созданы черзе window.open. По крайней мере кроссбраузерно.